# How can we fix the 'trait' tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [trait](/questions/tagged/trait) tag is currently targeted at Scala traits: the wiki exerpt

> A scala trait is roughly the equivalent of an interface in Java. ...
>   etc

This is confusing, as there are several other languages that have this feature, so I suppose this must be remedied somehow.

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)) lists some of the languages, but the one that triggered this question was [php traits](http://php.net/traits)

Things I can think of are:

- rename the tag to [scala-trait](/questions/tagged/scala-trait), adding [some-language-trait](/questions/tagged/some-language-trait) and fixing all the questions that are now suddenly wrongly marked "scala-trait" to their specific language variant.
- keep the [trait](/questions/tagged/trait) tag specific to scala,  adding [some-language-trait](/questions/tagged/some-language-trait) and fixing all the questions that are (still) wrongly marked with "trait" to $language-trait.
- Keep the trait tag, re-forge it to mean general 'trait', and add a [scala-trait](/questions/tagged/scala-trait) and $langauge-trait tags. Least amount of work needed, but the current questions have now a less specific (but in some cases more correct) tag.

I would probably be in favour of the last one, as it is the one most likely to end up with the least wronly-tagged older questions?

And to add to this: how can we do this? I'm not really been looking into tags. I do have some reputation, but I don't know who can/should decide to rename things /  re-interpret tags

Answer (score 5):

As suggested in the question, I would propose to change the wiki of the current [trait](/questions/tagged/trait) to make it about the general concept of traits.

Then we could add language specific traits like [scala-trait](/questions/tagged/scala-trait) and[php-trait](/questions/tagged/php-trait) to suit the specific needs of those questions.

The only questions that would need some attentions are current questions about traits that are not also tagged with a language, especially those that didn't include [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) because trait was already scala-only. These should be limited in amount, and probably not too hard to find? The other solutions seem more work for less-solid results.

I do not know however how to implement this / who has enough rights for it?